# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘Rcompression’

Tags: r, error-handling, rselenium

I am running a piece of code from RSelenium. I want to use my own Firefox browser profile to scrape websites.

I am trying to run:

```
fprof <- getFirefoxProfile("C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/x51kgfa5.default")
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```

Unfortunately I am getting the Rcompression error.

I have tried to locate an Rcompression package, but without any luck. Any thoughts on a possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a link on the CRAN page https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSelenium/. And with your favorite web search engine, https://github.com/omegahat/Rcompression.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I found the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the package if you `useBase = TRUE`:

```
fprof <- getFirefoxProfile("C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/x51kgfa5.default", useBase=TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof)
remDr$open()
```