# Error installing the Rcompression package

Tags: r

I have downloaded *RCompression* and copied the files to the library directory. I renamed the file from "Rcompression-master" to "Rcompression", then I ran

```
library(Rcompression)
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Error in library(Rcompression) : 
‘Rcompression’ is not a valid installed package
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not the way to install a package. Please specify your OS.

Answer (score 5):

As @Pascal states in the comments, copying files over is not the proper way to install a package.

The *Rcompression* package is offered by [omegahat.org](http://www.omegahat.org/) and is installable via that repository with

```
install.packages("Rcompression", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

Alternatively, you can install the package through omegahat's [github repository](https://github.com/omegahat) using the *devtools* package.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("omegahat/Rcompression")
```

Run `install.packages("devtools")` if you do not already have the *devtools* package installed.

Note that this will probably help answer [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171682/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rcompression) now ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't make the connection with the linked question. Good point.

Comment: I installed the new version of R 3.2 and ran the install_github command, but I am getting an error:
* installing *source* package 'Rcompression' ...
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rcompression'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/Rcompression'
Error: Command failed (1) I also tried to run install.packages("Rcompression", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R"), but that gave the following error: Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcompression’

Comment: @PCdL - Did you try the first code line? `install.packages("Rcompression", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")`

Comment: Yes, I also tried that one, sorry was still busy editing the comment ;)

Comment: Yep, from that error is seems you need to add `type = "source"` to the call.  So try `install.packages("Rcompression", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")`

Comment: It did download the package, but in another location ‘C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyWfsZK\downloaded_packages’

Comment: @Richard Scriven Yes, I am

Comment: Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Rcompression'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/Rcompression'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library" C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyWfsZK/downloaded_packages/Rcompression_0.94-0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rcompression’ had non-zero exit status

This is what I get with source added

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by using the correct (newer) repository:

```
install.packages(packageName, repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```